# how to print method variables using frida

Tags: javascript, android, frida, objection.js

this is my method i want to print the value of session id and device id , this is my code also suggest some documentation where i can learn more about frida

```
  public static String generateHashForDeviceSignature() {
    String sessionId = AppUtil.getSessionId();
    if (AppUtil.getDeviceId() == null || AppUtil.getDeviceId().equals("")) {
        AppUtil.setUniqueDeviceID(AppUtil.getAppContext());
    }
    String deviceId = AppUtil.getDeviceId();
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(new byte[1024]);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(sessionId)) {  deviceId = sessionId + "|" + deviceId;
        }
        try {
            MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            instance.update(deviceId.getBytes());
            byte[] digest = instance.digest();
            int length = digest.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", new Object[]{Integer.valueOf(digest[i] &255)}));             
            }
        } catch (Exception unused) {
        }
        return sb.toString();
        }
     }
```

this is my method i want to print the value of session id and device id ,
this is my code also suggest some documentation where i can learn more about frida.

```
    Java.perform(() => {
    var classInstanceIdResult = Java.use('com.androidapp.main.utils.CryptoUtil');
    var classInstanceIdAppUtil = Java.use('com.androidapp.main.utils.AppUtil');
    var getTokenMethod = classInstanceIdResult.generateHashForDeviceSignature.overload();
    var getgetDeviceId = classInstanceIdResult.getDeviceId.overload();
    var getgetSessionId = classInstanceIdResult.getSessionId.overload();
    // replace the getToken() method with out own implementation
    getTokenMethod.implementation = function () {
    // call the orignal method
     var ret = getTokenMethod.call(this);
    // do something with ret
    console.log("deviceId: " + ret.deviceId);
    console.log("Token: " + ret);
    return ret;
    };
```

I can print the final out put of the method but saying undefined on variable console log.

Comment: You can not access variables of a method using Frida, this is impossible. You wrote that you want session and deviceid. Based on your code I would hook `AppUtil.getSessionId();` and `AppUtil.getDeviceId();` as you did it with `getTokenMethod`? Note that questions about recommendations or links to external sources are considered of-topic, so please concentrate on the code.

Comment: public static String getSessionId() {
        String string = PreferenceManager.getString("sessionId");
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(string)) {
            return string;
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: this is the code for get session id which inheriting the other manager which is making it undefined . any help ???

Comment: Sorry I don't unterstand what you want to tell me by your last comments. Simply hook `AppUtil.getSessionId()` and print the return value. Or hook `PreferenceManager.getString` and only print the result if the request parameter was "sessionId".

Comment: $borrowClassHandle' of undefined this is the error i am facing